# Plot of ODE solution

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

can help to graph on z-axis

NDSolve[{f''''[z] + f'''[z] + 1000 f''[z] == 1, y[-(1/2)] == 0, y[1/2] == 0, y''[-(1/2)] == 0, y''[1/2] == 0}, y[z], z]

Comment: In your code, you use sometimes `f[z]` and sometimes `y[z]`. Turn it to the same notation. Besides, using `NDSolve` you need to fix the boundaries of the interval of integration of your equation. So, fix it. After that go to Menu/Help/WolframDocumentation/NDSolve and have a look at the very first example given there. You will see, how to plot it.

Answer (score 1):

As Alexei mentioned, you need to name your functions consistently:

```
sol = NDSolve[
       {f''''[z] + f'''[z] + 1000 f''[z] == 1,
        f[-1/2] == 0, f[1/2] == 0,
        f''[-1/2] == 0, f''[1/2] == 0},
       f, {z, -10, 10}
      ];

Plot[f[x] /. sol, {x, -10, 10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 0):

[`DSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DSolve.html) can find an exact solution

```
Clear["Global`*"]

eqns = {f''''[z] + f'''[z] + 1000 f''[z] == 1, f[-1/2] == 0, f[1/2] == 0, 
   f''[-1/2] == 0, f''[1/2] == 0};

sol = DSolve[eqns, f, z][[1]] //
  ReplacePart[#,
    {-1, -1, -1} -> FullSimplify@#[[-1, -1, -1]]] &

(* {f -> Function[{z}, (1/8000000000)
   E^(1/2 (-1 - z))
     Csc[Sqrt[3999]/4] Sec[Sqrt[3999]/
     4] (Sqrt[3999] E^(
       z/2) (-1 + E - 2 z - 2 E z + 4 Sqrt[E] z Cos[Sqrt[3999]/2]) + 
      2 E^((1 + z)/2) (-251999 + 1000000 z^2) Sin[Sqrt[3999]/2] + 
      2 E^(1/4) (Sqrt[3999] Cos[1/4 Sqrt[3999] (1 - 2 z)] - 
         Sqrt[3999 E] Cos[1/4 Sqrt[3999] (1 + 2 z)] + 
         1999 (Sin[1/4 Sqrt[3999] (1 - 2 z)] + 
            Sqrt[E] Sin[1/4 Sqrt[3999] (1 + 2 z)])))]} *)
```

Verifying the solution,

```
And @@ eqns /. sol // Simplify

(* True *)

Plot[f[x] /. sol, {x, -10, 10}]
```

[image]